# Installing an extension by having only the files and folders of it (no zip archive installation file)

Tags: extensions, installation

The wonderful image slider extension DJ Image Slider is not available for download, as I tried yesterday and today.

Now, I have installed the same on one of my websites, so I used filezilla to upload files and directories under com-djimageslider component.

I understand in order to install to another website, I cannot proceed through Extension Package File route (Upload Package File).

What am I missing?

Comment: Was able to install DJ Image Slider through Install from Web route which surprisingly so long missed my attention. Nevertheless, I am curious to know the process of installing an extension armed with files and directories of an extension retrieved through filezilla from another website.

Answer (score 6):

If I understand right your question, you are after the **Discover Feature** in the **Extensions Manager**.

First, make sure you have copied all the required files of an extension to their proper directories -wherever those may exist: administrator site, media, languages and so on-, otherwise you will encounter issues using this extension later on.

Then, go to the **Extensions -> Discover** (from left menu) - click the **Discover button**. It will list all extensions that may exist in the Joomla folder structure that have not been installed. You can select the one that you want to install and install it from there.

## Update:

Well, you could upload the extension's files to the corresponding folders at the Joomla site you want to install it and then do the discover procedure.

Otherwise, you could re-compile the extension into a "installation bundle" in zip format and install it as usual. You can read its xml file to see its original files/folders structure, in order to organize the files accordingly, prior to compressing them.

Comment: I mean on my desktop I have now a folder which includes all files and directories retrieved through filezilla from another website where DJ Image Slider is installed. Can I install DJ Image slider through Joomla Admin backend (instead of filezilla) now to a fresh website using the desktop folder. This query is just for curiosity as the purpose is solved as mentioned earlier.

Comment: @BagraRajeev: See updated answer.